# Tabulator, change the title of the column when exporting the tabulator table to an excel file

Tags: tabulator

I have a tabulator table that i need to export to xlsx with different titles than the table titles.
Example;

```
  { title: "Sub Division", field: "xxx", sorter: "string", headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter xxx xxxx", headerFilter: "input" },
```

when i export to the excel i want the title to be "Sub_Division"

Can I change the title of the column when exporting the tabulator table to an excel document?

Answer (score 1):

Yes see http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/download

```js
const tabledata = [{
    name: "Oli Bob",

  },
  {
    name: "Jamie Newhart",

  },
  {
    name: "Gemma Jane",

  }
];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: "100",
  virtualDom: false,
  data: tabledata,
  columns: [{
      title: "Row Num",
      formatter: "rownum"
    },
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      downloadTitle: "Changed  Name",
      width: 200
    },
  ],
});

function download() {
  table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx", {
    sheetName: "MyData"
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.5.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
<button onclick="download()">Download Excel (with changed name)</button>
```